# SQL SELECT - Select only if another record exists

Tags: mysql, sql

In the example below, I wish to display data for only 1904 players who have a 1903 record. What would I add to the SQL to accomplish this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM pitchers 
WHERE year = 1904 

+------+-----------+-----------+-----+-----+
| year | playerID  | nameLast  | IP  | ER  |
+------+-----------+-----------+-----+-----+
| 1903 | mathech01 | Mathewson | 366 |  92 |
| 1903 | youngcy01 | Young     | 341 |  79 |
| 1904 | mathech01 | Mathewson | 367 |  83 |
| 1904 | walshed01 | Walsh     | 110 |  32 |
| 1904 | youngcy01 | Young     | 380 |  83 |
+------+-----------+-----------+-----+-----+
```

Using the above table example, I only wish to collect the 1904 data for Mathewson and Young, and not include Walsh (since he did not have a 1903 record).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM pitchers p
WHERE p.year = 1904 and
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pitchers p2 WHERE p2.playerID = p.playerID and p2.year = 1903);
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will allow you to change the year in just one place. It assumes a business rule where you'll only ever have one row per (playerID,year):

```
SELECT thisyear.*
FROM pitchers AS thisyear
INNER JOIN pitchers AS lastyear
    ON lastyear.`playerID` = thisyear.`playerID`
    AND lastyear.year + 1 = thisyear.year
WHERE thisyear.year = 1904
```

Comment: I did not try this one. Just because I'm more familiar with EXISTS than INNER JOIN.

Comment: @user2140857 - But notice his use of lastyear vs thisyear.  It may (or may not) be part of what you _really_ needed.